# how to get order details based on shipment increment id in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I tried to get an order details in shipment tracking page based on shipment  increment id.but unable to get order collection.

```
$parentBlock = $block->getParentBlock();
    $track = $block->getData('track');
    $email = $block->getData('storeSupportEmail');
    $shipId = $block->getData('ship_id');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $shipmentCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment'); 
        $shipment = $shipmentCollection->loadByIncrementId($shipId);
        $orderId = $shipment->getOrderId();
        echo $orderId;
```

Comment: any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

if you are loading with shipment id like `10` then below code will work:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$shipmentCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment');
$shipment = $shipmentCollection->load($shipId);
$orderId = $shipment->getOrderId();
echo $orderId;
```

OR if you try with shipment increment id like `000000001` then your code will work:

```
$shipmentCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment'); 
        $shipment = $shipmentCollection->loadByIncrementId($shipId);
        $orderId = $shipment->getOrderId();
        echo $orderId;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have order id  then get order using below code:

```
$orderRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface'); 
$order = $orderRepository->get($orderId);
```